# a way to set the size for my UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hello all I was wondering if there was a way to create some sort of frame for the UIViewcontroller

for instance like so ( i know it doesn't work) :

```
  UIViewController *example = [[UIViewController alloc]  
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 55)];
```

a bit like the UIWebview

```
 UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 100)];
```

if anyone has an idea I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 5):

You should set controller's view frame instead:

```
example.view.frame = CGRectMake()
```

Comment: Hi - this seems to "chop off the right hand edge". This has the effect of losing the curved corner on that side. Is there some way of controlling this?